# Error while installing packages in Azure functions (Visual Studio)

Tags: python, visual-studio, azure, package, azure-functions

I am trying to install package tldextract in azure functions, but unable to. The package is present in the python index provided in azure functions documentation, but still unable to import.

Help me in installing packages in Azure functions.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paT1L.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure to include the `tldextract` module in the requirements.txt file, which is located at the root of your project directory.

[image: requirements.txt]

And then import it in your code:

```
import tldextract
```

Here is my sample function:

```py
import logging, tldextract
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    domain = tldextract.extract("https://www.goodreads.com/").domain

    if domain:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Domain is: {domain}")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
             status_code=200
        )
```